# MediatorLiveData calls old data before addSource's observed LiveData returns

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, mediatorlivedata

Below, is the method I have in my repository:

```
public LiveData<Trail> getRandomTrail() {
    final LiveData<Trail> currentRandomTrail = trailDao.getRandomTrail(getMaxRefreshTime());

    randomTrail.addSource(currentRandomTrail, trail -> {
        if (trail == null) {
            loadTrailsFromNetwork();
        } else {
            randomTrail.removeSource(currentRandomTrail);
            randomTrail.postValue(trail);
        }
    });
    return randomTrail;
}
```

This problem is that the UI briefly displays outdated data, but I am expecting the MediatorLiveData object, randomTrail, to wait until currentRandomTrail has returned it's value. Outdated data first appears, then the MediatorLiveData object updates. Any idea why my MediatorLiveData object is not working how expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why my MediatorLiveData object is not working how expected?

This happens because first `getRandomTrail()` will be executed, returning a `MediatorLiveData` object with an outdated value. Only after execution of this method has finished, the next method can start running. So the following snippet will never be finished in time to return *randomTrail* with a current value from the surrounding method `getRandomTrail()`:

```
trail -> {
    if (trail == null) {
        loadTrailsFromNetwork();
    } else {
        randomTrail.removeSource(currentRandomTrail);
        randomTrail.postValue(trail);
    }
}
```

One approach to deal with this situation:

When you start loading the current data in `getRandomTrail()`, let *randomTrail* have some value which will be recognized as invalid by the `ViewModel`/ the UI.
That way, you can prevent showing outdated values - maybe show some type of progressbar instead.

Comment: I simply added randomTrail.setValue(null) at the start of the method and it worked! I'll also implement a loading bar somehow. Thanks for the help. However, is this issue normal? It seems to be a bit of a workaround. I'm wondering if there's not a better way I should design my code to prevent this outdated value from being called.

Comment: @Amboseli - afaik this is the normal behavior. Another more complicated approach I've seen (in some codelab) is having a generic class Result<T> with subclasses Success<T> (this one has a field data of type T), Loading<T> and Error<T> (this one has e.g. a field of type Throwable). Then one can expose  a LiveData<Result<T>>